# How can I serialize an XML document with 2 different lists?

Tags: c#, xml, list, serialization, asp-classic

OK I'm using ASP MVC and am trying to load some XML data which I need to serialize as I'm converting it to JSON.

What I'm failing to understand is, my XML has more than one descendant. So, when I serialize it, in the  model I need to store the data from each descendant in its own list right?

I've done that, so I've got two seperate lists. So, how can I serialize this all into the one XML doc?

This is an example of my XML markup:

```
<vehicle>
<make>Suzuki</make>
<color>Yellow></color>
<owner>
    <id>0</id>
    <name>Joe Bloggs</name>
</owner>
<owner>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Foo Bar</name>
</owner>
</vehicle>
```

Here's my XML model:

```
    public partial class vehicle
    {
        private string makeField;
        private string colorField;

        private vehicleOwner[] ownerField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string make {get; set;}

        /// <remarks/>
        public string color{get; set;}

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("owner")]
        public vehicleOwner[] owner{ get; set;}

        // Keep this in a list to serialize it
        List<vehicle> vehicleList = new List<vehicle>();
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class vehicleOwner
    {

        private int idField;

        private string nameField;


        /// <remarks/>
        public int id { get; set;}


        /// <remarks/>
        public string nameField {get; set;}


        // Stick it in a list so I can serialize it later
        List<vehicleOwner> vehicleOwnerList = new List<vehicleOwner>();
    }

}
```

So, now I have my two lists containing XML data: vehicleOwnerList and vehicleList.
But these are all the one XML document. So how can I serialize this for both lists? Would I have to merge them into one list, and if so how would I do that?

So I.E.

```
 List<vehicleOwner> listCombinedActions = new List<vehicleOwner>();

                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                XPathNavigator nav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
                using (XmlWriter writer = nav.AppendChild())
                {
                    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<vehicle>), new XmlRootAttribute("owner"));
                    ser.Serialize(writer, listCombinedActions);
                }
```

Cheers

Comment: First try to change `Element` attribute to `Array` attribute of `owner` property and `typeof(vehicle)`. Also you can use xsd.exe tool to generate class from xml with commands `xsd.exe your.xml` `xsd.exe your.xsd /classes`

Comment: Ok - and if I change it, how will this impact it? The data is still stored in two separate lists. I need to serialize both these lists into the one XMLDoc. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by saying stored in two lists? And why do you need XmlDocument?

Comment: Ok - maybe I'm doing something wrong. Take a look at the XML model I posted. There are two parts to the XML document: the vehicle and the vehicleOwner. For each part I've had to create a list to populate it. Is there a way I can create one list for both of these different types?

Comment: Lets start from beginning. You have xml file and you want to read its data to your objects?

Comment: Ok In the XML file, there are 2 different elements.
Now - I'm using ASP MVC to read from this XML file. I want to loop through the contents of each element and append the data to a list so that I can easily convert it to JSON later.
In the model, I have defined two lists for each element because they are different types. However, is there a way I can do this without using two lists? Can I use one? That would make the serialization process much easier. Otherwise, how can I serialize it into the one object when there are two seperate lists?

Comment: So you want to DEserialize(process when you transfer data from xml to objects). Ok I add example in answer it might help you because now you have a bit mess in your code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood what you trying to achieve so adding example how it could be done:

---

Data models:

```
//NOTE: property, root class names is different. 
//So you can name it what you want but you need to specify xml tag name in attribute

[XmlRoot("vehicle")]
public class vehicleObject
{
    public string make { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("owner")]
    public List<vehicleOwner> ownerList { get; set; }
}

public class vehicleOwner
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("name")]
    public string nameField { get; set; }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
vehicleObject yourWorkingObject;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\a.xml")))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(vehicleObject));
    yourWorkingObject = serializer.Deserialize(ms) as vehicleObject;
}

//Do with yourWorkingObject here what you want
```

---

Result:

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks for this - I really do appreciate it. But what I'm confused about now is how would I then convert this to JSON? I've been using the JSON.Net library which has this method: JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(XMLDoc to be serialized) - doing it from my original code was easy because I had that XMLDoc reference

Comment: I'am not familiar with Json, but I think it should be a way to convert OBJECT to json.

Comment: Well I found Json.Net library documentation. There should be [JsonConvert.SerializeObject](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html) method. So what you need to do to get Json is this: `string myJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourWorkingObject);`

Comment: Note for the future: do not stick on one thing, explore and you will find new ways to reach your goal.

Comment: I love you! Can I deliver a beer to your house? - Thanks - appreciate it.